# How to add/use colon ":" in the YML value?

Tags: properties, yaml

How to add/use colon `:` in the `YML value`?

```
spring:
  application:
    name: app
  profiles:
    active: DEV
  config:
    import: configserver:
```

The above example `configserver:` give error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quotes `""` works

```
spring:
  application:
    name: app
  profiles:
    active: DEV
  config:
    import: "configserver:"
```